Identify an action movie
I am looking for the title of one movie I saw several years ago.
I am not sure if all the things I "remember" are correct but this is what I managed to summ up so far:
The movie is probably western and it is regular acted action movie with emphasis on martial arts.
Main heroes are two - one male and one female. I think they are siblings and are probably asian.
They are both trained in martial arts and I think the female is stronger fighter.
They both trained in the same school - or at least one flashback in the movie suggests so.
In said flashback the boy is about to fight some other students but he is interrupted by the girl who beats them instead of him. (This part is rather unclear.)
I think one of the two protagonists is a cop/detective. 
The plot of the movie turns around stopping a bad guy who maybe has something like metal arms or similar oddity that gives him great power. 
This is important for one of the final scenes where the male protagonist fights him and actually manages to fully finish his, as I would call it, battle trance entering ritual.
This is one thing I am completely sure of - the male protagonist is shown multiple times during the movie as he tries to enter some sort of battle trance. He does that by standing for a few seconds while saying something like "gli gli gli gli" while he has his arms spread out and slowly lowering them. Important is the vocal part.
However until the final battle, it is never shown how would this affect him since he usually gets interrupted. In the flashback scene by the female who skips him over and takes care of the combat and later in the movie in similar fashion. 
The movie is probably from between 1997-2005 but I am more guessing this.

Was it anime by any chance?

@DustinDavis The movie is not an anime, will include it in the question, ty.

Based on your description, I think it's Silver Hawk (2004). 
Check the following plot from Wiki.

Silver Hawk riding her motorcycle through China. She is chasing thugs
  who have stolen pandas and are getting away in a truck. She attaches
  her bike to the truck, jumps on top of and fights the men in the truck
  until they give up. She heads back to Polaris City (located where Hong
  Kong is in our world) where she meets an old childhood friend, Rich
  Man. Then a flashback occurs, going back to the martial arts training
  academy.
He is the new head of the police department. He recognizes Lulu,
  Silver Hawks's name in real life, from magazine covers. He tells her
  of his mission to arrest Silver Hawk. When they arrive at the airport,
  he asks for her phone number, but she asks for his phone instead. She
  implants a tracking chip so she can overhear his conversations and
  agrees to a date if he can recall who she is.

Female and Male protagonists, Lulu and Rich Man:

Bad guy with metal arms:

I don't think they were blood related siblings but definitely yes, Lulu takes care of Rich Man as a big sister. And yes, there was a scene in the movie where the guy when he was little being bullied by other kids, Lulu defends him and fights with other kids and if I remember correctly, Lulu gets punished and during the punishment, Rich Man comes and gives her coconut water or some drink. Lastly, there were scenes where Rich Man enters battle trance and says something funny like "gli gli gli".

"Rich Man"... a name so creative I'd fear getting killed by the Blue Bomber.

This is exactly the movie I was looking for. Also, really good form of answer - pictures and everything. You rock! Thank you.

You're welcome.
